# Data not reloading when switching between tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I've a `UITabBarController` with two tabs. In each tab there is a table, and in the `viewWillAppear` I load the data and reload the table:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    loadTasks()
}

func loadTasks(){
let url = Api.GET_TASK_USER_MONTH
    Task.getTasks(url) { tasks in
        if !tasks.isEmpty {
            for index in 0...tasks.count-1 {
                self.tasks.append(tasks[index])
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

But every time I switch between the tables the data displayed is wrong. It fires displays the second's tab data, then it displays OK the first one and then it displays the one's data all the time in the two views.

Any ideas?

UPDATED: My loadTasks() method.

Comment: I suggest to let `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear`

Comment: I've already done that, but with no luck... thanks a lot!

Comment: show some more code how you are doing with tableView.

Comment: I load the data from the Database in a `tasks` variable. When it finishing loading I call the `self.tableView.reloadData()`.
Then I have the `tableView` methods, regarding to the protocols `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: Try to put breakpoints on datasource methods of both view controllers and check whether they are working properly or not.

Comment: then what's your prob, can you update your ques with more info.

Comment: A likely problem is that your database connection is done async and that it hasn't completed at the time you run the `self.tableView.reloadData()`.
It's hard to see if you don't actually share the code in loadTasks though.

Comment: @Rajat I see that when I load the value in the text of the cell that the first two times it load correctly, but then it is not... it gets the data from the `tasks` variable, but it doesn't update it. It is like my `loadTasks()` is not being call after the two first times...

Comment: @Moriya Yes, it does. I have a callback, I'm using Alamofire, and I load the `tasks` variable after getting the data from the Database. I have updated the post with the method. 
`

Comment: @SarahMarciel, could you share that callback then?

Comment: @SarahMarciel you have to debug it using breakpoint to get what is going wrong, did you try putting breakpoints on cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @Moriya post updated with the method.

Comment: Are you keeping the two tableviews in the same controller? or are you using two instances of the controller? or two different implementations of controllers? @SarahMarciel

Comment: @Moriya There are two different controllers, yes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are there any differences in the two controllers? Also, how are you defining your  self.tasks? Shouldn't mix the data from the different controllers but it seems it would never be emptied and perhaps therefor fill up with same data duplicated over and over.

Comment: @Moriya the differences are the data loaded in the `tasks`variable (the Database response). The `tasks`variable is defined this way: 
`var tasks: [Task] = [Task]()`
Can the tasks variable be mix between the two controllers?

Comment: No, that should be the source of you issue. But you might want to do self.tasks = [] before loading the data in loadTasks() so that you don't get duplicates. 

Have you set a breakpoint in viewWillAppear to check if it's actually running every time you switch tabs?

And have you checked that it's the correct view controller that is displayed when switching tabs?
@SarahMarciel

Comment: I have done that, but I think the problem is that the `viewWillAppear()` is not being called after the two first times the tabs are loaded...

Answer (score 1):

Normally `viewWillAppear` should be called if you "enter" the tab.
It might be the case that the ViewController gets not deinitialized => the ViewController is still there and therefore `viewWillAppear` will not be called.

You might need to use a weak self in `loadTasks`:

```
func loadTasks(){
    let url = Api.GET_TASK_USER_MONTH
    Task.getTasks(url) { [weak self] tasks in
        if !tasks.isEmpty {
            for index in 0...tasks.count-1 {
               self?.tasks.append(tasks[index])
            }
        }

        self?.tableView.reloadData()
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to test this and give feedback.

Comment: @Sarah I'd also suggest that you should use `reloadData()` on the main thread, so `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: It didn't work... I think the problem is that the View Controller is not initialized or something, because my loadTask() method is not being called after the two first times...

Comment: does the deinit get called when entering the other tab? 

    `deinit {
        print("yep")
    }`

Comment: @MattLeFleur Done that, didn't work either... thanks a lot!

Comment: @d.felber where should I put the `deinit { print("yep") }` ? Thanks!

Comment: @d.felber I've put it in my Task class, and yes, it gets called everytime I go through the tabs.

Comment: @SarahMarciel No. Not the Task class. Just put it somewhere in one of your TableViewControllers.

Comment: @d.felber I've put it in my TableViewControllers and it is not called, thanks!

Comment: @SarahMarciel Just to clarify: the code from your question is in one of the TableViewControllers - not in the TabBarController - right?

Comment: @d.felber Yes, from the TableViewControllers.